# How to augment the ObjectDefinitionBlock when definiting a type in GraphQL Nexus.js?

Tags: typescript, graphql, nexus-js

I am using nexus.js to build GraphQL schema. To define a type, we use [`ObjectDefinitionBlock`](https://nexusjs.org/docs/api/object-type#objecttype). I define the object type as following:

```
export const Choice = objectType({
  name: 'Choice',
  definition(t) {
    t.id('id', { resolve: (x) => x.id.toString() });
    t.string('value');
    t.int('order');
  }
});
```

The `t` is a `ObjectDefinitionBlock` that allows to define object fields. The `x.id` is a `bigint` type and is serialized as a built-in GraphQL scalar type - `ID`. Since, I use `bigint` for all my database Ids, I have to always add a resolver to convert `bigint` to `string`. I want to augment this `t` so that I can write:

```
t.bigId('id');
```

Note that I don't want to define a **new scalar**. Just need to write a facade over the scalar `ID` to avoid writing repetitive definition for `resolve` function. **Is there any way to achieve this?**